# Comparing Strings for palindrome

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I reverse a string using [::-1] can I then just compare it to the original to test if it is a palindrome? My other plan is to create a list or set with the alphabet in it and index the letters of the string to compare numerically if the simple way doesn't work out.

Comment: ... did you try it out??? Why do you think it won't work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can.

```
def is_palindrome(a_string):
    if a_string == a_string[::-1]:
        return True
    return False
```

Or simpler:

```
def is_a_palindrome(a_string):
    return a_string == a_string[::-1]
```

Comment: `if True: return True`?

Comment: It checks out...